# How to pass operators in expressions in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am reading **Root of Lisp**, and come across this example:

```
(
 (lambda (f) (f '(b c)))
 '(lambda (x) (cons 'a x)))
```

However, if I evaluated it in `Emacs`, I got

```
Symbol's function definition is void: f
```

If I try it on https://repl.it/languages/scheme, where it uses Schema as the lisp interpreter, I got

```
Error: ('lambda ('x) ('cons ('quote 'a) 'x)) is not a function [(anon), (anon)]
```

If I remove the `quote` on the 2nd lambda expression,  this example works on repl.it, but still got the same error on Emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the function `f` to `'(b c)` must be done using [`funcall`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html). So the following works:

```
(
 (lambda (f) (funcall f '(b c)))
 '(lambda (x) (cons 'a x)))
```

and evaluates to `(a b c)`.

Paul Graham is probably using some variant of lisp with only one namespace for function names and data variables (*Lisp-1* or Scheme model) in his [article](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/ldc/llog/jmc.pdf) whereas Elisp is a *Lisp-2* language with different namespaces for functions/variables. This allows to have the same name for a function and a variable.

So for something like

```
(some-function some arguments)
```

the elisp executor only searches `some-function` in the function namespace which makes a construct like `funcall` or `apply` necessary when you want to call a function associated with a variable from the variable namespace.

The separate function/variable namespace in elisp may lead to unexpected behavior if not understood:

```
(defun do-something () (1))
(setq do-something #'(lambda () (2)))

(do-something) ;; => 1
(funcall do-something) ;; => 2
```